# How many automorphisms does $S_3\times S_3$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I've shown that $|\text{Aut}(S_3\times S_3)|\ge 72$, how can I show that $|\text{Aut}(S_3\times S_3)|\le 72$ ?

Comment: how did you showed that there are more than $72$?

Comment: Hint. The elements of $S_3 \times \{1\} \cup \{1\} \times S_3$ are the only ones that commute with at least 12 elements of $S_3 \times S_3$.

Comment: @Dave : I did not understand how is that helpful... please elaborate a bit..

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik Consider what the image of $S_3 \times \{1\}$ must be under an automorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to show that the direct factors are the only normal subgroups of $G = S_3 \times S_3$ that are isomorphic to $S_3$. That implies that any automorphism must either fix both direct factors or interchange them. Since ${\rm Aut}(S_3) \cong S_3$, there are $36$ that fix them both, and another $36$ that interchange them.

You could show first that there are only two normal subgroups of order $3$, and then show that there is only one way to extend each of them to a normal subgroup of order $6$.